# IIS Url Rewrite with special characters in route

Tags: mvc

Нужно перенаправить запросы содержащие /p?Id= на другой url. 
Например:
с http://localhost:2711/p?Id=555 
на 
http://localhost:2711/places/555

Использую UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter

Но мой маршрут почему-то не работает:

```
<add name="place2dirrewrite"   
    virtualUrl="^/p\?Id=(.*)$"  
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"  
    destinationUrl="/places/$1"   
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: почему нельзя задать маршрут через RouteCollection?

Comment: @Dmitry, очевидно чтобы не хранить в RouteCollection устаревшие маршруты, которые более не используются приложением (но на них могли остаться внешние ссылки).

Comment: @PavelMayorov думаю в вашем случае подошел бы 302 редирект

Comment: @Dmitry будьте внимательнее, пожалуйста! Вы уже во втором обсуждении меня с кем-то путаете...

Comment: @ PavelMayorov про устаревшие маршруты это ваше сообщение

Comment: @Dmitry да, но я ответил за автора. Ситуация довольно прозрачная.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну на самом деле ни кто не мешает использовать RouteCollection совместно с настройками в web.config, конечно же минуя UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter. Так сказать динамически загрузить недостающие маршруты. Когда надобность в них исчезнет то просто удалить их из конфига

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вот тут: `rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"` - эта строчка явно запрещает участие QueryString в процессе перезаписи. Кажется, нужное вам значение это атрибута называется `IncludeQueryStringForRewrite`

Comment: Спасибо! все работает